# Countdown timer bug after midnight (Related to Timezone and Clock )

Tags: java, android, github, timer, open-source

I've got a couple of users in my app reporting a weird behavior of a time reset/bug, i was baffled by it and after testing and collecting logs - i figured that my timer, if started before midnight, resets to 20+ hours instantly, i've can't figure out why or how to prevent this.

The project is open source and anyone is welcome to help me with this, here are the links:

[GitHub](https://github.com/Alikaraki95/Getoffyourphone)

Info about the app/project:

- Select apps, select desired lock-down time, lock apps.

[My Timer Class ( Full )](https://github.com/Alikaraki95/Getoffyourphone/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nephi/getoffyourphone/Timer_Service.java)

Time/Date related snippet

```
 public class Timer_Service extends Service {

public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 1000;
public static String str_receiver = "com.nephi.getoffyourphone.receiver";
public String str_testing;
Calendar calendar;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
String strDate;
Date date_current, date_diff;
//Root Detector
RootBeer rootbeer;
//Con Manager
WifiManager wifiManager;
//DH Helper
DB_Helper db;
Intent intent;
Intent lockIntent;
Intent Shame;
//Shame Int Counter
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Lock Screen launch
    lockIntent = new Intent(this, locked.class);
    lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:M:ss");

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);

    //Root Detector
    rootbeer = new RootBeer(this);
    //Wifi Manager
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    //DB
    db = new DB_Helper(this);
}  

public String twoDatesBetweenTime() {


    try {
        date_current = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        // Gets the first timestamp when the lockdown started
        date_diff = simpleDateFormat.parse(db.get_Data(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {


        long diff = date_current.getTime() - date_diff.getTime();
        int int_hours = Integer.valueOf(db.get_Hours(1));
        long int_timer;
        if (int_hours > 10) {
            int_timer = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(int_hours);
        } else {
            int_timer = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(int_hours);
        }
        long long_hours = int_timer - diff;
        long diffSeconds2 = long_hours / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes2 = long_hours / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours2 = long_hours / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;


        if (long_hours >= 0) {
            str_testing = String.format("%d:%d:%02d", diffHours2, diffMinutes2, diffSeconds2);
            Log.e("TIME", str_testing);

        } else {
            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Timer_Service.class));

            mTimer.cancel();
        }
```

Any suggestions ?

---

EDIT:

- Timer works fine, if someone sets the lockdown for example, 30 minutes, it will countdown 30 minutes and unlock when it's done.

Let's say someone started the lockdown at 21:30:00, timer will work just fine and end at 10:00:00.

However, if someone started the lockdown at 23:55:00 for 30 minutes, the "Time left to unlock" will jump to 21 hours, instead of 30 minutes. This only happens when a new day starts/timer starts before midnight.

Comment: There is far too much code here for us to be able to answer this question.  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (focus on "Minimal" and "Verifiable") that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's going on, when we don't know what values of `strDate` and `db.get_Data(1)` are and/or are supposed to be?

Comment: @JoeC I deleted codes that are not related to the issue. Is that better?

Comment: @Andreas I just added the declared variables, is it enough? Or should i add more explanation ?

Comment: Basically, what we need is enough code (and no more) that we can copy and paste into our IDE of choice, click Run, and see the issue within a minute or two.

Comment: @XerXes Declaring the variable doesn't help us. What are the *values*? --- Anyway, please follow the link in the first comment, **read it** to learn how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then write such an MCVE and replace all the code in the question when you have an MCVE that shows the problem.

Comment: @JoeC I don't think i can provide everything here in my post - although everything is in my github repo, even the issue i'm specifying here is posted as multiple issues in my repo - i tried fixing it a lot of times and checking why this is happening but couldn't figure it out. Did you understand the issue in the first place or should i add more explanation for it?

Comment: @Andreas Okay, thanks for the clarification. I'll try it and edit my post later, as i can't right now.

Comment: @Andreas And get_data gets the saved current timestamp from the db. This timestamp is saved when i start the lockdown.

Comment: @XerXes So "Current date" actually means "Start date/time", and "hours" actually means "Hours to wait. No, minutes to wait. Well, it depends"? Not confusing at all (<- sarcasm).

Comment: @XerXes *"I don't think i can provide everything here in my post"* You can't write code where you initialize `date_current`, `date_diff`, and `int_hours` with hard-coded values that shows the problem, followed by the *relevant* parts of the code doing calculation, ending with a `print` statement that shows the (incorrect) calculated result, with a comment explaining what the correct/expected result would be? *Really?!?*

Comment: @Andreas Yes, exactly.  Get_Hours returns the hours you selected for the lockdown, and you can select 30 minutes.

Comment: @XerXes So if I want 5 minutes or if I want 15 hours, I'm out of luck? Why not just always store it as minutes. If you want 3 hours, you store it as 180 minutes. Much better than storing a "minutes" value in an integer field named "hours".

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, i just saw your example of a demo-code. I'll add that tomorrow most likely and edit my whole post. Regarding your last comment, for now you can select 30 mins, 1, 2 & 3 Hours. Feature requests include a customised hour selector will be implemented once i'm a little free for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you have the time stored in "H:m:ss" format, but you are ignoring the date aspect. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you the milliseconds after Jan 1 1970. So this includes the date aspect. Taking the difference of the two values will give you the milliseconds expired, which you can check against any time interval for the elapsed time.

Do this instead:

When saving the time for the timer should start use the millisecond instead of H:mm:ss :

```
long millisNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

save millisNow to the database.

And save the time that should elapse:

```
int minutes = 30;
long millisElapse = 30 * 60 * 1000;
```

save this to the database (or which ever time interval you need)

now get the difference

```
long diff = timeNow - timeDatabase;

if(diff > millisElapse){
    //end session
}
```

BTW: The format you posted "H:M:ss". The capital "M" stands for month(!) not minutes.

Take a look at the documentation on the "Date and Time Patterns"  [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

Comment: Oh okay, so i'm actually taking the wrong difference of both dates, i am indeed saving my date in db as h:m:ss .. i'll try this and debug it tomorrow. Thank you so much for your information!

Comment: Even if you were to save the entire date as `yyyyMMddHHmmss` the conversion using `new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss");` would still just return something like: 23:55:22 which has no reference to the date.

Comment: I've implemented the code and tested it - it works on my device, but i'm waiting for a couple of users to test it as well and will report back. Thankyou so much for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Your profile has you located in Germany. I lived in and around Aachen for 20yrs. I just got tired of the rain! Moved back to the US.

Comment: Oh really ? I go to Aachen almost every month, i got people there! Haha yeah the rain makes it terrible >.<